# Disable empty power slot on Cisco 2960xr

Tags: cisco, cisco-commands, cli, cisco-2960

I have a ws-C2960XR-24ps-I switch with 2 slots for power supply's but only 1 power supply inserted.

So the switch is always logging an event : "%PLATFORM_ENV-1-FRU_PS_ACCESS: FRU Power Supply is not responding". When I try to disable it by running
[image]

I get "power supply is not present" in response. Is there a way to disable that slot so it stops sending these log messages that there is a missing power supply?

[image: sh env cmd]

I just want the specific log to stop without keeping it from logging any issues with the slot that is in use.

Comment: Is the switch part of a stack? what IOS version is it running?

Comment: no it is not part of a stack, IOS version is 
Cisco IOS Software, C2960X Software (C2960X-UNIVERSALK9-M), Version 15.2(2)E3, R                                   ELEASE SOFTWARE (fc3)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect that this log message is not caused by the absence of the PSU but by an IOS bug (e.g. [CSCuv53498](https://tools.cisco.com/bugsearch/bug/CSCuv53498) but there are more), so upgrading it may get rid of the messages.

Alternatively, configure the following to just hide the syslog messages:

```
logging discriminator FOO msg-body drops FRU Power Supply is not responding
logging buffered discriminator FOO
```

(replace "buffered" with other type of logging as required)

Comment: So now how do I apply this to the logs being sent to syslog server?